# jQuery toggle hide/show div; how to prevent to hide div when click again on the same anchor

Tags: jquery, toggle

I have 2 divs which toggle when click on anchor.
Click on anchor 1; div 1 is shown, div 2 is hide.
When clicking second time on anchor 1; div 1 also hides. This should not be!
How can i prevent that?

I tried this with `if( !$(this).closest('li').hasClass('.active') ) {` but this does not work

```js
$('.showSingle').click(function() {

  if (!$(this).closest('li').hasClass('.active')) {

    $('.active').closest('li').removeClass('active');
    $(this).closest('li').addClass('active');
    $('.targetDiv').not('#div' + $(this).attr('target')).hide();
    $('#div' + $(this).attr('target')).toggle();

  }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li class="active">
  <a class="showSingle" target="1">Show div 1</a>
</li>
<li>
  <a class="showSingle" target="2">Show div 2</a>
</li>

<br /><br />

<section id="div1" class="targetDiv">
  Content div 1
</section>

<section id="div2" class="targetDiv" style="display:none;">
  Content div 2
</section>
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xtynvb0h/1/)

Comment: There's a typo breaking your code. Remove the period in hasClass('.active') here and everything works as intended: `if (!$(this).closest('li').hasClass('.active')) {`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Almost.

This is simpler and works

```js
$(function() {
  $('.showSingle').on('click', function() {
    const target = $(this).attr('target');
    const $li = $(this).closest('li');
    $('li.active').removeClass('active'); // remove all active 
    $li.addClass('active');
    $('.targetDiv').hide(); // hide all
    $(`#div${target}`).show();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li class="active">
  <a class="showSingle" target="1">Show div 1</a>
</li>
<li>
  <a class="showSingle" target="2">Show div 2</a>
</li>

<br /><br />

<section id="div1" class="targetDiv">
  Content div 1
</section>

<section id="div2" class="targetDiv" style="display:none;">
  Content div 2
</section>
```

However as comments say, do not use target, instead use data-attributes or in my opinion better, href

```js
$(function() {
  $nav = $('#nav').on('click', '.showSingle', function() {
    const target = $(this).attr('href');
    const $li = $(this).closest('li');
    $('li.active', $nav).removeClass('active'); // remove all active 
    $li.addClass('active');
    $('.targetDiv').hide(); // hide all
    console.log(target)
    $(target).show();
  });
});
```

```css
a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="nav">
  <li class="active">
    <a class="showSingle" href="#div1">Show div 1</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a class="showSingle" href="#div2">Show div 2</a>
  </li>
</ul>

<br /><br />

<section id="div1" class="targetDiv">
  Content div 1
</section>

<section id="div2" class="targetDiv" hidden>
  Content div 2
</section>
```

Here is a CSS improvement since it will show the target div if linked from outside

```js
$(function() {
  const $nav = $('#nav').on('click', '.showSingle', function() {
    const target = $(this).attr('href');
    const $li = $(this).closest('li');
    $('li.active', $nav).removeClass('active'); // remove all active 
    $li.addClass('active');
  });
  const hash = location.hash || $('.showSingle').first().attr('href');
  if (hash && hash.startsWith('#div')) {
    $activate = $nav.find(`[href="${hash}"]`);
    if ($activate.length ===1) $activate.closest('li').addClass('active');
  }  
});
```

```css
a {
    text-decoration: none;
}

.active { background-color: green }
.targetDiv {
    display: none; /* Hide all targetDiv elements by default */
}

.targetDiv:target {
    display: block; /* Show the targetDiv if it's the target of the URL fragment */
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="nav">
  <li>
    <a class="showSingle" href="#div1">Show div 1</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a class="showSingle" href="#div2">Show div 2</a>
  </li>
</ul>

<br /><br />

<section id="div1" class="targetDiv">
  Content div 1
</section>

<section id="div2" class="targetDiv">
  Content div 2
</section>
```

Comment: `1` and `2` are invalid values for `target` attribute. Here are some valid ones:  `_blank`, `_parent`, `_self`, `_top`

Comment: `$('li.active')` as a selector is asking for trouble. We should rather use `data-group` and `data-target` attributes and move with that logic onward.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan It was late and you are correct. Can you look at the other two examples I posted?

Comment: In such case, using *hash* targets in `href` and by not using `Event.preventDefault()` — you don't need JS at all: https://jsfiddle.net/L93e7gw2/ Also, `$nav` is leaking into *global* scope.

Comment: That is eactly what I am doing in the 3rd example. I am not using event.preventDefault in any of my examples and I AM using the hash in the href. With OP's HTML you do however need to use JS if you want to have the link have the active class. The global $nav was a typo. I missed a const